Difference-in-Difference with treatment defined after event
I am working through a scientific paper which uses a difference-in-difference design, which, however, is not your standard DID setting.
Think about the case where we collect observations of multiple firms across multiple time periods. At $t=0$ there is an event. So far so basic. Now the deviation from the standard setting: Instead of knowing which firms are in treatment and control group, the treatment group is defined as those firms for which the observable characteristic $x$ changed from $0$ to $1$ from pre-event to post-event. The control firms are those firms for which the characteristic $x$ remained at $0$.
Is this a common/known version of a DID-design? If so, I would be happy if you could provide me with some literature because I haven't found anything coming close to this.

Depends on x...If x is an independent variable, left to "random" chance, this is a perfectly normal DID design, with no special name (e.g. x=firm adopted a mandatory "Return to Office" RTO policy. And y=turnover in employees, or productivity of employees, etc.). Thiis is what you need to do for an observational study. But if x is the dependent variable, then of course you have a tautology, and this is a very poor study design. And then x (IV) may be somehow correlated to y (DV); then again it is a bad design (e.g. x=RTO, y=employee commute time).

X is an independent variable. But it is an endogenous variable. It measures whether the firm was covered in the newspaper media. The event is supposed to change the degree to which firms are covered in the media. We then define treated firms as those firms whose news coverage changed from before to after the event. Our y is different, but could be anything stock market related for example.

Thanks for the additional details. TL:DR: there is nothing inherently wrong with endogenous factors. But they bring the possibilities of  significant issues. And depending on the fine details of your study (we know who hides in the details...), I am afraid that you may have one of these cases.
All observational studies can only use endogenous factors, because you cannot randomly administer the "treatment". For example, studying any effect based on gender, age groups, university major, etc. Or studying the hospital stay duration for 2 conditions, or for the same condition at 2 hospitals, etc. So it is done all the time (and I am not sure it has a “special” name).
But these observational studies are not randomized controlled studies, and because of this, we need to be more careful, as you intuited. In your case I see 2 possible issues.
The first one is with the “intervention” or “treatment”. For the study to be valid, all interventions need to be equivalent. But it is clear that any 2 media appearances are not equivalent. The front page of the Wall Street Journal (WSJ) is not the same as the back page of the Modesto bee; a 60 Minutes expose is not the same as a 2 minutes segment on local news. All this amounts to comparing apples with oranges. Now, you can be much more specific about the media coverage (e.g. it is only articles on the front page of the WSJ -or of the Financial Times-). But even then, is it a positive coverage (quarterly results above analysts’ s expectations), or a negative one (below analysts’ s expectations), or neutral (CFO retiring). If you do not separate them you may see no effect, but not because there was no effect, but because they cancelled each other out. You will need to be able to say, w/o getting red in the face, that all the “events” you are considering are absolutely equally effective. So the event needs to be very specific, including the tone (positive/negative) of it. That is a tough challenge.
The 2nd one is that there may be hidden variable(s) which are responsible for both the IV and the DV. Media does not “randomly” cover a company. There is coverage because something newsworthy happened. That is the true causal factor. Media reported that company A got a new drug approved by FDA, or that company B’s CEO was indicted for tax fraud, or that flood caused company C’s plant to close temporarily, etc. The media coverage did not “cause” anything. The worst case is that the reason for the media coverage was exactly because of the good (or poor) stock performance (so in fact the DV “caused” the IV). In fact, observational studies can not prove causality; all they can do is prove correlation (but the OP tagged the question with “causality”).
This btw is related to the first point (lack of randomization). One could argue that the age, or gender, of subjects in an observational study is “random.” And the DV (e.g. smoking?) certainly did not cause the IV (gender). And no nuisance variable caused the IV (gender). But that is not the case for you. In fact, positive media coverage is indicative of companies having “good news” to share, so obviously this should have a positive impact on stock performance. I am afraid that we are bordering on tautology.
Maybe the specific details of your study avoid these traps? Perhaps? And if you face those traps, what could you do. I am afraid not much; this is a case of the good old GIGO acronym.
